# Unique pointer ownership

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I am having difficulties understanding the ownership of unique pointers. 
Can anyone explain how it is possible to store a pointer to a unique pointer in a set?

Example from SFML game dev book which illustrates the problem:

```
typedef std::pair<SceneNode*, SceneNode*> Pair;

typedef std::unique_ptr<SceneNode> Ptr;

std::vector<Ptr> mChildren;

void SceneNode::checkSceneCollision(SceneNode& sceneGraph, std::set<Pair>& collisionPairs)
{
    checkNodeCollision(sceneGraph, collisionPairs);

    for(Ptr& child : sceneGraph.mChildren)
        checkSceneCollision(*child, collisionPairs);
}

void SceneNode::checkNodeCollision(SceneNode& node, std::set<Pair>& collisionPairs)
{
    if (this != &node && collision(*this, node))
        collisionPairs.insert(std::minmax(this, &node));

    for(Ptr& child : mChildren)
        child->checkNodeCollision(node, collisionPairs);
}
```

Does this not defy the meaning of a unique_ptr? Since it is possible to access the actual object from the set and modify it.

Comment: @Cyber I think you are thinking about `shared_ptr`?

Comment: This is ok but it's up to you to make sure you don't access the object through a regular pointer, after it has been deleted by the unique_ptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this not defy the meaning of a unique_ptr?

No. `unique_ptr`, as you’ve said, specifies *ownership* semantics – and nothing else. In particular, it specifies that there is only one *owner* of the pointer, but it does not say anything about *access*. There can be as many accessors as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The unique ptr is accesses only via reference.  As such the ownersip in both cases never changes the container is the owner of ptr.

```
 for(Ptr& child : mChildren)
        child->checkNodeCollision(node, collisionPairs);
```

In this case for each contained pointer a reference is created the reference never invokes move or copy semantics therefor doesn't participate in the ownership.